# How to do a context dependant layout in Qt Designer and PyQt5?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, designer

I have a group box or the like containing a combobox and some more widgets that shall not all be visible at the same time. Depending on the selection I want at the same place to be displayed a button **or** a line edit **or** a (second) combobox. So if combobox entry one is selected it shows the button, if entry two is selected it shows the line edit, if entry three is selected it shows the second combobox, while not showing the other two.
I know that I can do it all dynamically but this results in a lot of code lines. I want to use QT Designer and a grid layout and I can't see how to put two widgets at the same place and then make only one visible programmatically.
I hope I could explain properly.

I played with Qt Designer but could not place two widgets over one another in a grid layout.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Without seeing any code I'm only guessing but it sounds like you might want to use a [`QStackedWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you G.M.
Yes, I was looking for QStackedWidget. I wasn't aware of this at all. I tried it and it works easily out of the box.